# filter data.frame based on reactive input

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), B = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), C = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), D = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), E = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), F = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), G = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), Y = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I would like to filter this dataframe and remove missing values in the columns (D,E,F,G,Y). I'm doing this using 'complete.cases' in the following code:

```
completeFun <- function(data, desiredCols) {

   completeVec <- complete.cases(data[, desiredCols])
   return(data[completeVec, ])
 }
```

However, what I noticed is that when I call the function, e.g.: `completeFun(test, c('E','F')` the following output is returned:

```
  A B C    D E F    G    Y
1 1 1 1    x x x    x    x
3 1 2 2 <NA> x x <NA>    x
4 1 2 2    x x x <NA> <NA>
```

which is removing the rows where `E OR F` are `NA` and only keeping the rows where `E AND F are NOT NA`.

However, what I want instead, is to keep the rows where any one of those columns (E,F) is `NOT NA`, i.e, `neither E nor F == NA`, which means this output in this case:

```
  A B C    D    E    F    G    Y
1 1 1 1    x    x    x    x    x
3 1 2 2 <NA>    x    x <NA>    x
4 1 2 2    x    x    x <NA> <NA>
5 2 1 1    x <NA>    x <NA> <NA>
```

Of course I would like to keep the function as flexible as possible to be able to include more columns into the calculation.

What is the best R way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer of Sotos, here is a case that does not work based on his answer:

```
structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), B = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), C = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), D = structure(c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), E = structure(c(1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, NA), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), F = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), G = structure(c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), Y = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Y"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

For this new data frame, if I call the function as follow: `completeFun(test, cols = c('E','F', 'Y'))` I get the following output:

```
      A  B  C    D    E    F    G    Y
1     1  1  1    x    x    x    x    x
NA   NA NA NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3     1  2  2 <NA>    x    x <NA>    x
NA.1 NA NA NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
NA.2 NA NA NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

which is missing the last row of the dataframe where `F AND Y` have a non-empty value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via `rowSums`, i.e.

```
completeFun <- function(df, cols) {
    return(df[rowSums(df[cols] == '') != length(cols),])
}

completeFun(dd, cols = c('E', 'F'))
#  A B C D E F G Y
#1 1 1 1 x x x x x
#3 1 2 2   x x   x
#4 1 2 2 x x x    
#5 2 1 1 x   x  

completeFun(dd, cols = 'Y')
#  A B C D E F G Y
#1 1 1 1 x x x x x
#3 1 2 2   x x   x
```

---

**EDIT**

In the previous example OP had empty spaces instead of `NA` hence, we were checking for them. If we want to check for `NA`s we can modify the function and check with `is.na` instead.

```
completeFun <- function(df, cols) {
    df[rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) != length(cols), ]
 }


completeFun(df, cols = c('E','F', 'Y'))
#  A B C    D    E F    G    Y
#1 1 1 1    x    x x    x    x
#3 1 2 2 <NA>    x x <NA>    x
#4 1 2 2    x    x x <NA> <NA>
#5 2 1 1    x <NA> x <NA>    x
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, please look at the updated question (dataframe) as the answer does not work in the case of 3 cols as variables.

Comment: @ifreak you first had empty spaces ("") instead of `NA` in your first example, update the answer to `df[rowSums(is.na(df[desiredCols])) != length(desiredCols), ]` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sotos' answer, except it is a bit more flexible.
A row is considered complete if the number of non-NA values is equal to, or more than the threshold `thrsh`.

```
completeFun <- function(dtf, cols, na.val="", thrsh=1) {
    dtf[dtf == na.val] <- NA
    ix <- rowSums(!is.na(dtf[, cols])) >= thrsh
    dtf[ix, ]
}

completeFun(test, cols=c("E", "F"))
#   A B C    D    E F    G    Y
# 1 1 1 1    x    x x    x    x
# 3 1 2 2 <NA>    x x <NA>    x
# 4 1 2 2    x    x x <NA> <NA>
# 5 2 1 1    x <NA> x <NA> <NA>

completeFun(test, cols=c("D", "E", "F", "Y"), thrsh=3)
#   A B C    D E F    G    Y
# 1 1 1 1    x x x    x    x
# 3 1 2 2 <NA> x x <NA>    x
# 4 1 2 2    x x x <NA> <NA>
```